# How to edit dynamic page

Tags: php, javascript, css, edit

Learning how to code by editing an existing dynamic pages site that is live.
Have a question on how to edit dynamic pages.
For ex: I want to edit static text on a page.  I can figure out stuff using firebug and seeing html, nodes, etc but I have no idea how to find the correct/relevant file on my server to edit and make changes the static text so something else.  I see CSS files, js files.  Is it a php file maybe?  Where should I look?  Maybe other files?  Can't seem to figure out!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the URL? That might give a clue as to how it's being built.

Answer (score 1):

If the text comes out of a database/CMS, you'll have to search the database.

If the text is hard-coded in the code itself, use a search utility on that set of folders to find a match.

You can't always tell looking at the output on the client to determine the source unless you're familiar with the code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. when you say database..do you mean mysql?  My CMS is built in symphony php.  So do I look in backend php files then?